# how to read/write sequnce of bits bit by bit in c++

Tags: c++, character-encoding, bit, huffman-code, read-write

I have implemented the **Huffman** coding algorithm in C++, and it's working fine. I want to create a text compression algorithm.

behind every file or data in the digital world, there is 0/1.

I want to persist the sequence of bits(**0/1**) that are generated by the Huffman encoding algorithm in the file.

my goal is to save the number of bits used in the file to store. I'm storing metadata for decoding in a separate file. I want to write bit by bit data to file, and then read the same bit by bit in c++.

the problem I'm facing with the **binary mode** is that it not allowing me to put data bit by bit.
I want to put "10101" as bit by bit to file but it put asci values or 8-bits of each character at a time.

### code

```cpp
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ofstream f;
    f.open("./one.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
    f<<"10101";
    f.close();

    return 0;
}
```

### output

[image]

any help or pointer to help is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Files (streams) work at least on byte level. There is no way to put individual bits into a file. You have to collect your bits in bytes and write the latter.

Comment: @Scheff so I need to make a buffer of 8 bits then process them?

Comment: A buffer of 8 bits? You mean a byte aka. a `char` or `unsigned char`?

Comment: You'll have to code your own mechanism to write to bytes (that's easy), but the smallest you can write to the file is a byte at a time.

Comment: I would expect that you compress into a container of `unsigned char`s. Thereby, it might happen that not all bits of the last byte are used. However, there is no way to store parts of a byte (neither in memory nor in a file). You have to remember this else where. (Usually, unused bits are just set to default values e.g. 0.)

Comment: thank you all, I got it, I just need to handle edge cases with buffer concept.

Comment: For development, if you don't mind the waste of file space, you may find it convenient (for debugging & diagnostics) to read/write `'0'` and `'1'` characters rather than doing the bit-to-byte buffering.

Comment: thank you @Scheff, I do that, take care of edge cases.

Comment: @Eljay thank you, but I want to create a text compression algorithm for my portfolio project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Binary mode" means only that you have requested that the actual bytes you write are not corrupted by end-of-line conversions. (This is only a problem on Windows. No other system has the need to deliberately corrupt your data.)

You are still writing a byte at a time in binary mode.

To write bits, you accumulate them in an integer. For convenience, in an unsigned integer. This is your bit buffer. You need to decide whether to accumulate them from the least to most or from the most to least significant positions. Once you have eight or more bits accumulated, you write out one byte to your file, and remove those eight bits from the buffer.

When you're done, if there are bits left in your buffer, you write out those last one to seven bits to one byte. You need to carefully consider how exactly you do that, and how to know how many bits there were, so that you can properly decode the bits on the other end.

The accumulation and extraction are done using the bit operations in your language. In C++ (and many other languages), those are `&` (and), `|` (or), `>>` (right shift), and `<<` (left shift).

For example, to insert one bit, `x`, into your buffer, and later three bits in `y`, ending up with the earliest bits in the most significant positions:

```
unsigned buf = 0, bits = 0;

...

// some loop
{
   ...

   // write one bit (don't need the & if you know x is 0 or 1)
   buf = (buf << 1) | (x & 1);
   bits++;

   ...

   // write three bits
   buf = (buf << 3) | (y & 7);
   bits += 3;

   ...

   // write bytes from the buffer before it fills the integer length
   if (bits >= 8) {     // the if could be a while if expect 16 or more
       // out is an ostream -- must be in binary mode if on Windows
       bits -= 8;
       out.put(buf >> bits);
   }

   ...

}

...

// write any leftover bits (it is assumed here that bits is in 0..7 --
// if not, first repeat if or while from above to clear out bytes)
if (bits) {
    out.put(buf << (8 - bits));
    bits = 0;
}

...
```